# Length of one side of a triangle

Tags: geometry

It's been over 50 years since I studied geometry.  I want to know the answer to the following:

I have a very narrow needle like triangle. Angle A is very small.  Side a is 150.0 feet.

Side b is inclined 76.5 degrees to side a  ( Angle C)

and side c is 281.2 degrees inclined to side a   (Angle B )

What is the length of either side b or c?

Or, am I all screwed up and need some book learning?

Comment: degrees or percent?

Comment: Do you really mean $281.2$ degrees?

Comment: Hint: try to sketch the triangle..

Comment: What are the vertices of the triangle?

Comment: @Fred Perhaps you remember the sides are lebeled with small letters and angles are in large case. If what I edited is not what you meant, please feel free to switch it back.

Comment: I shot the angles with a compass.  Side a is at 114 degrees magnetic and exactly 150 feet long.  Side b is 37.5 Degrees magnetic and Side c is 35.2 degrees magnetic.  I'm trying to determine the distance to a spot in the distance.  I think it's about 1130 yards.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the angle between sides $A$ and $C$ is $360^\circ-281.5^\circ=78.5^\circ$.  That means the angle opposite $A$ is $180^\circ-78.5^\circ-76.5^\circ=25^\circ$.  Now use the law of sines  $\frac {\sin A}a=\frac {\sin B}a$ to get $B=\frac {\sin 25^\circ \cdot 150}{\sin 78.5^\circ}\approx 64.69$
Note that the nomenclature in the law of sines does not match yours.  The angles are $A,B,C$ with the sides opposite $a,b,c$